# How to create shortcut to desktop app in the all apps menu using Visual Studio Installer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

In my solution I have a Windows desktop project and a Visual Studio installer setup project. The Windows project is just for testing purposes and does not have any UI.

I want to configure my installer project to install my Windows app and create an entry in the all apps list in the start menu, however I don't see any way of doing this.

The only way I have found that I can create an entry in the all apps list is by creating and installing a UWP app.

How do I create an entry for my Windows app?

Comment: I have not done this, but have you followed the instructions on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3bb4tfd(v=vs.100).aspx) under the "Optional Deployment Capabilities" section?

Comment: I'm surprised that this article doesn't mention this. A little bit of poking around and I was able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

In the Visual Studio installer setup project, in the solution explorer, right click on the project and go to view file system.

Right click on 'File System on Target Machine' in the file system menu, and go to 'add special folder'. Add 'User's start menu'. Cut and paste shortcut of primary output into the start menu.